# Huawei USG OSPF P2MP Network Limits

Tags: ospf, huawei

Good day! Configured an L2TP over IPSec tunnel on Huawei USG6500E. On the tunnel interface prescribed ospf type p2mp. I connect clients to this tunnel. When 32 clients are connected, the OSPF neighborhood hangs in the Init state until you disconnect another neighbor from the tunnel. I can't find information about this limitation anywhere. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help, but to increase your chances of getting helped you better add a diagram with addresses and related configs, and what is the software version?